# Nullpointer on initialization of JavaFX view

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX to show a view from my game.

The View is loaded when I call the method in my `MainApp` class:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    //fields

    public MainApp() {
        this.game = new Game();
    }

    //lots of other methods

    public void showGameView() {
        try {
            System.out.println(game.getPlayer().getCurrentRoom());
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/GameView.fxml"));
            AnchorPane GameView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            rootLayout.setCenter(GameView);
            GameViewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }
```

The `Game` object stores some information and stuff. The controller looks the following:

```
public class GameViewController {

    private MainApp mainApp;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        mainApp.getGame().  ... //do something else
    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }
```

I have always done it that way. When the controller gets loaded, the `MainApp` objects gets set in the controller and I can work with that. But now I get a Nullpointer when any `mainApp.get...` gets called. The field `mainApp` is null. I dont really know what the deal is here, because as I said it worked like this in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really just an extension to fabian's answer. I agree that you should create the controller instance yourself (remove the `fx:controller` in the FXML as he said). It allows you to declare stuff as `final` which you otherwise wouldn't be able to, and avoids you having to have loads of setters in your public API which you otherwise wouldn't need.

You could probably move a lot of your `initialise` code into the constructor. I usually only put code in `initialise` if it directly modifies any of the JavaFX widgets.

It would look something like this:

```
public void showGameView() {
    try {
        System.out.println(game.getPlayer().getCurrentRoom());
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/GameView.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new GameViewController(this));
        AnchorPane GameView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(GameView);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GameViewController {

    private final MainApp mainApp;

    public GameViewController(MainApp mainApp)
    {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        mainApp.getGame().  ... //do something else
    }
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty good and simple solution. And I guess its cleaner style than what I first thought in the comment on the other answers. Thank you aswell!

Answer (score 2):

The `initialize` method of the controller class is invoked at the end of the `FXMLLoader.load` method invocation, i.e. before you do

```
controller.setMainApp(this);
```

which means at this time the `mainApp` field still contains `null`.

You have to move the code dereferencing `mainApp` from the `initialize` method to the `setMainApp` method, create the controller instance with initialized `mainApp` property yourself and pass it to the `FXMLLoader` before loading (requires removal of `fx:controller` attribute) or using a controller factory to initialize the controller instance (which is probably the most complicated of the options).

Comment: Ok so the field is empty because the field gets set after the `initialize()` gets called. I guess just calling another `init()` method in the `setMainApp()` is some kind of unclean but I guess I have to take it that way. Thank you

Comment: @Master1114 The usual approach would be to call `mainApp.getGame(...)` etc from the `setMainApp(...)` method; but if you want an additional `init()` method there is nothing to stop you doing that.